# delete all but X most recent folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can someone provide a batch script that will delete all but the X most recently modified folders in a directory. I've looked at [How do I delete old files from a directory while keeping the most recent ones on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902/how-do-i-delete-old-files-from-a-directory-while-keeping-the-most-recent-ones-on), but that was based on an absolute time window rather than a relative ordering of modification dates.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep the 10 latest log files based on modification date:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=10 delims=" %%a in (' dir *.log /o-d /a-d /b ') do echo del "%%a"
```

Remove the **echo** to make it perform the deletions rather than just display them.

Comment: used rd /S /Q to silently remove entire non-empty directories, but this worked.  Thanks!

Comment: For the latest 5 folders I used: FOR /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a IN (' DIR %DEST% /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q "%DEST%\%%a", where %DEST% is the path to the folder.